# Tree Selection SAPUI5 (with checkboxes). Auto check child nodes when parent node is checked

Tags: css, tree, sapui5

I have a Tree element with MultiSelect mode, which looks good with checkboxes in every tree item. I wanted to make it so if I select one item, all of its children get selected as well. I have the tree in the view:

```
 <Tree selectionChange="onPress" itemPress="onPress" includeItemInSelection="true" mode="MultiSelect" items="{path: '/'}" id="Tree">
    <headerToolbar> 
       <Toolbar> 
          <content> 
             <Title level="H2" text="Title"/> 
             <ToolbarSpacer/> 
          </content> 
       </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <StandardTreeItem title="{text}"/>
 </Tree>
```

I wanted to know if SAPUI5 had a property for its trees like "Check Children" or something similar. And if not, how could I do it.

Thanks.

Comment: create a custom TreeNode control with a checkbox property, and override the `renderNode` method in the `sap.ui.commons.TreeRenderer` class to display that checkbox when needed

Comment: but sap.ui.commons.TreeNode is deprecated since version 1.38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches that come to mind:

- Using binding (the 'better' way).
- Using JS manipulation (the 'harder' way - because the [TreeItem](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.TreeItemBase.html) has no method for retrieving the child items).

I will show you the 'better' way for doing things. The 'harder' one you can do as an extension of this method (if you really want to go that way, I can also add info about how to do it).

Basically you need to extend your model by adding a `selected` flag. Assuming that you have a typical model structure (as in the explored example), you can use this function:

```js
function addSelectedFlag(aNodes, bSelected) {
    jQuery.each(aNodes, function(iIndex, oNode) {
        oNode.selected = bSelected;
        if (oNode.nodes) {
            addSelectedFlag(oNode.nodes, bSelected);
        }
    });
}
```

Then, when the selection changes, you can do something along the lines of:

```
onSelect: function(oEvent) {
    var aItems = oEvent.getParameter("listItems") || [],
        oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    jQuery.each(aItems, function(iIndex, oItem) {
        var oNode = oItem.getBindingContext().getObject(),
            bSelected = oItem.getSelected();
        if (oNode.nodes) {
            addSelectedFlag(oNode.nodes, bSelected);
        }
    });
    oModel.refresh();
}
```

When you specify the template fro your item, you must also bind the selection:

```xml
<StandardTreeItem title="{text}" selected="{selected}"/>
```

I made a working JsFiddle out of this: https://jsfiddle.net/n4frtzd8/1/